# Remove debugging C++ code in vscode: How do I step into a compiled library but stop in the source code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a library that is stored in $HOME/mylibrary and that I'm building from source using cmake. I'm installing this library in something like $HOME/.local and I also have some code in a separate project that uses that library.

When I debug my source code and step into the code from the library sometimes it stops into the code from $HOME/mylibrary and sometimes in files from $HOME/.local. How can I make it to stop only in code from $HOME/mylibrary?

Comment: Is this Linux with GDB?
 When you say “sometimes” what do you mean? Is it completely random?

Comment: not completely random - it is repetitive if I restart the debug process. It is random in a sense that some files are loaded from one location some from the other. But if I restart the debug process these will be loaded from the same locations. For example my.h will always be loaded from first location and my.cc always from the second.

Comment: yes it is Linux with gdb